# C++ typedef and return types: how to get the compiler to recognize the return type created with typedef?

Tags: c++, typedef

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    typedef int myInt;
    int k;
public:
    A(int i) : k(i) {}
    myInt getK();
};

myInt A::getK() { return k; }

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    A a(5);
    cout << a.getK() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

myInt is not recognized by the compiler as an 'int' in this line:

```
myInt A::getK() { return k; }
```

How can I get the compiler to recognize myInt as int?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`typedef` creates synonyms, not new types, so `myInt` and `int` are already the same. The problem is scope — there is no `myInt` in a global scope, you have to use `A::myInt` outside of the class.

```
A::myInt A::getK() { return k; }
```

Answer (score 3):

`A::myInt A::getK() { return k; }`

You have to qualify the `typedef` type because you created it inside the class `A` scope.

Answer (score -2):

Put the definition outside of the class.